# OpenVPN Server and Client - Can No Longer Connect To Network?

Tags: openvpn

A few weeks ago my OpenVPN server within my home network was running like a dream. I connected and I could access my network and access the internet. It was amazing.

Tonight, I can connect to the OpenVPN, I can ping my server IP through the tunnel, but none of the clients on the home network. I also can't connect to the internet through my OpenVPN connection.

How do I even begin to go about troubleshooting this please? I've tried rebooting the server but it didn't fix it. Could anyone tell me what the most likely setting to be lost over a reboot is please?

Thanks

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.90.10.9      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
10.90.10.0      10.90.10.9      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.90.10.9      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
host86-134-200- 192.168.43.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       10.90.10.9      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

- 192.168.168.0 is my home network
- 192.168.43.1 I think is my wireless connection away from home
- 10.90.10.1 is my openvpn tunnel server

---

Edit to answer questions:

- If I ping 10.90.10.1 I get a response. If I ping 192.168.168.2 which is on my home network, I get no response.
- *"What is ok your client machine?"*
  I'm not sure what you mean by this. I happen to have 2 client machines, both have the same issue, both were working perfectly. Both now no longer work.
- I only connect to my OpenVPN server - which is on my home network - when I'm away from home. I may be using public wifi or mobile internet. Neither work.

Comment: This is not clear: *"but I can ping my server IP through the tunnel"*. Can you ping your server through the vpn or you can't? Edit your question, make it more clear. What is ok your client machine? How do your home network machines reach your server, are you sharing the vpn tunnels with them, if yes, how? Edit all of these into your question, or it will be closed as an unclear question.

Comment: Do you have anything showing in your syslog, or wherever your client sends its logs?

Comment: Nothing obvious in my logs. Can't see anything referencing openvpn/tun at all though.

Answer (score 0):

As two client systems have the same problem I would start searching for broken routing on your OpenVPN server.

- Version 1: packets originating from your VPN cannot reach the LAN
- Version 2: reply packets from your LAN don't know the route to the VPN server
- Version 3: the routes on your VPN server got garbled (LAN interface restarted, OpenVPN still running, but bringing up the LAN cleared the routing table).

Comment: One thing I notice about my routing table is that there is no mention of the 192.168.168.0 network. Should I have something like push "route 192.168.168.0 255.255.255.0" in the server.conf?